# Why did I get an error message: wrong-type-argument stringp user-init-file

Tags: debugging

I have `(set-register ?E '(file . user-init-file))`, so that I can easily jump to my config file.  Previously I used a string to specify the path to my init file, but I figured I'd tidy it up a bit.

However, it doesn't work, and emacs complains about `(wrong-type-argument stringp user-init-file)`, giving the following stack trace with `debug-on-error` enabled.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (wrong-type-argument stringp user-init-file)
  expand-file-name(user-init-file)
  find-file-noselect(user-init-file nil nil nil)
  find-file(user-init-file)
  ad-Orig-jump-to-register(69 nil)
  jump-to-register(69 nil)
  call-interactively(jump-to-register nil nil)
```

For reference, this happens if I load emacs with -Q, and then eval the `set-register...` and then attempt to jump to the register.

What's going on here? Things like `(find-file user-init-file)` don't throw this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your code `user-init-file` is not evaluated (it is quoted), so `expand-file-name` gets a symbol (and not a string), and complains about that.

Try this:

```
(set-register ?E (cons 'file user-init-file))
```

PS: You can also use the backquote:

```
(set-register ?E `(file . ,user-init-file))
```

PPS: A side note: as far as I can tell this case is hard to debug by running emacs with `-Q`: `user-init-file` evaluates to `nil` under `emacs -Q`, so

```
(set-register ?E `(file . ,user-init-file))
(jump-to-register ?E)
```

fails for a different reason.